# pipe curl output to email

Tags: bash, curl

I want to pipe output from the curl command to the email however I receive an empty attachment file when I run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

STATUS=$(curl -I example.com)

echo $STATUS | mail -s "Test" an@email.com
```

I've also tried to group into a block but this also didn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash    
{
curl -I example.com
} | mail -s "Test" an@email.com
```

OS: Red Hat 6.3

```
# mail -V
12.4 7/29/08
```

Comment: Curriously, your commands seem correct (both). What version of `mail` are you using, try this in a freed environnement.

Comment: Question updated with the mail version

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your mail binary is [this one](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mail), try adding the option `-a -`.

Comment: Thanks for reply but it didn't help I'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

Try simply

```
curl -SIo /dev/stdout example.com 2>/dev/null | mail -s "Test" an@email.com
```

Well, if it's a mail problem. Your description seem strange, which version of mail are you using?

or maybe asking for `sendmail` directly:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail an@email.com < <(
    echo $'From: an@email.com\nTo: an@email.com\nDate: '$(
        env LANG=C date +%c)$'\nSubject: Test'
    echo
    curl -SIo /dev/stdout 2>/dev/null example.com)
```

You could even build some more sophisticated job:

```
MyVar="$(curl -SIo /dev/stdout 2>/dev/null example.com)"
/usr/sbin/sendmail an@email.com < <(
    echo $'From: an@email.com\nTo: an@email.com\nDate: '$(
        env LANG=C date +%c)$'\nSubject: Server resp: '${MyVar%%$'\r'*}
    echo
    echo "$MyVar")
```

So you could have the initial server response in the **subject**.

This is not a *reserved* `sendmail` feature!

I was using this kind of method from many years, first under `sendmail`, but this work **with the same syntax** (ie calling `../sbin/sendmail` binary or wrapper directly, with a formated mail as header + empty line + body ) with all *MTA* I've ever used upto now (sendmail, qmail, postfix, exim).

**Nota** Some (old) MTA complain about presence (or not) of a *CR* or `\r` at end of lines, maybe some `sed 's/$/\r/'` could help.

Comment: Hi, this also attached an empty file. I would like to pipe this into message body.

Comment: Did you need only the header or the output of curl (transfer stats) too?

Comment: This also creates an attachment. Basically I just monitor a website and if it's down I would like to know the header output from curl but it looks like it's not easy to pipe it into message body and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Did you try the `sendmail` proposed solution?

Comment: No I didn't. This is a simple BASH script so I would like to stick to `mail` and I've got postfix installed anyway. Is the `mail` and `curl` working for you?

Comment: `postfix`, like every `MTA` offer a `/usr/sbin/sendmail` wrapper! Try it!

Comment: Yes, `curl -SIo /dev/stdout 2>/dev/null www.test.com | mail -s test myself` work fine, but I'm Debian user, on *squeeze*, with bash 4.1.5(1)-release and `mail` is coming with my version of *Exim* (not postfix). At all, I know this work under postfix too!

Comment: @HTF I'v tried now, under `postfix` **exactly** the same syntax as my last sample whith `MyVar...` and using `sendmail` sbin command. This work perfectly : I've recieved a mail with subject: `Server resp: HTTP/1.1 200 OK` (postfix version 2.7.1-1+squeeze1)